# Sass Function to target dynamic classes

Tags: css, sass

I am having an issue targeting a class in sass that is almost the same in all elements but just changes the last part and I am not sure on how to do it.

The class is based on user id like below:

```
<div class"user_143"></div>
<div class"user_341"></div>
............
```

I want to create styles for all classes that end in a multiple of 10 + 1 or +2 etc.

For example all classes anding in 1 get a `backgound-color` all those in 2 get a different `backgound-color`

Is that possible to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the attribute selector, where, in below case, it targets all elements with a class that starts with `user` and end with a number

*If it's only the `user` classes that ends with a number, drop the first selector `[class^="user"]`*

```css
div[class^="user"][class$="1"] {
  color: red;
}
div[class^="user"][class$="3"] {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="user_143">Number 3</div>
<div class="user_341">Number 1</div>
```